# How to view MAC address by hardware device?

Tags: linux, networking

Is there an easy way to view MAC address by hardware device? I know you could sling together a whole bunch of Bash logic with sed to do this but I figure there has to be an easier way to get this info. Ex: You have a server with a whole bunch of network cards and you want to see MAC address by device? I can figure out how to manually correlate them or I can just pull the info from IPMI but Linux always seems to have a fast way to do things - I just don't know what it is in this case. What I'm looking for is something like:

```
<Some command>

NIC 1 - Intel x710
<its MACs>
NIC 2 - MLX5
<its MACs>
NIC 3 - Broadcom Whatever
<its MACs>
```

Something like that. The important thing is determining the model of the network card: Mellanox MLX5, Intel x710, etc

Answer (score 1):

`ip link` shows exactly this.
Mine looks roughly like

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 4000 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:aa:bb:bb:cc:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:01:02:03:04:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:0F:0E:0D:0C:0B brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

There's no "not much shell logic" way of mapping Linux network interfaces to "device names" (like your "NIC 1 - Intel x710"), especially in the context of things like multi-port SFP+ cards like the x710; these are designed to offer virtual functions, so the mapping of "one Linux network device belongs to one hardware device" simply works in neither direction.

Comment: Sincere apologies, I failed to make the example I wrote clear. The model of the card is the important piece I know how to match the MAC to just the OS' device name

Comment: as said, since there's not really a 1:1 mapping from OS device names to hardware devices, there's no simpler way to do this than to take a few guesses and detours through PCI device listings, as described in Grant's answer. Generally, a OS network device might not map to any hardware device, or to a group of different hardware devices, and especially, there can be many OS network devices that map to the same hardware device.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all MAC addresses of your network cards with:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/*/address
c8:5b:76:9e:65:9a
22:60:04:08:f0:37
00:00:00:00:00:00

34:f3:9a:01:e6:22
```

So you could easily extend that to:

```
$ ( cd /sys/class/net/ && for i in *; do printf '%s: %s\n' "$i" $(cat "$i"/address); done )
enp0s31f6: c8:5b:76:9e:65:9a
ipv6leakintrf0: 22:60:04:08:f0:37
lo: 00:00:00:00:00:00
tun0: 
wlp3s0: 34:f3:9a:01:e6:22
```

But really, parsing the output of the `ip` command [given by Marcus Müller](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/681305/22222) is your best bet:

```
$ ip link | awk '$1~/^[0-9]*:/{printf "%s ", $2} /^ /{print $2}'
lo: 00:00:00:00:00:00
enp0s31f6: c8:5b:76:9e:65:9a
wlp3s0: 34:f3:9a:01:e6:22
ipv6leakintrf0: 22:60:04:08:f0:37
tun0:
```

And, if you want that as a single command, just make it into an alias. Add this line to your shell's initialization file (`~/.bashrc` if using `bash`):

```
alias getMac="ip link | awk '\$1~/^[0-9]*:/{printf \"%s \", \$2} /^ /{print \$2}'"
```

Then, open a new terminal and:

```
$ getMac 
lo: 00:00:00:00:00:00
enp0s31f6: c8:5b:76:9e:65:9a
wlp3s0: 34:f3:9a:01:e6:22
ipv6leakintrf0: 22:60:04:08:f0:37
tun0:
```

Comment: Sincere apologies, I failed to make the example I wrote clear. The model of the card is the important piece I know how to match the MAC to just the OS' device name

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave this open in case someone comes up with something cleaner but what I ended up doing was combining `lspci` and `ethtool`:

```
[root@gputest ~]# lspci -v | grep Ethernet
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
31:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller E810-XXV for SFP (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet 25G 2P E810-XXV OCP
31:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller E810-XXV for SFP (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet 25G 2P E810-XXV OCP
98:00.0 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT2892 Family [ConnectX-6 Dx]
98:00.1 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT2892 Family [ConnectX-6 Dx]
b1:00.0 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT28800 Family [ConnectX-5 Ex]
b1:00.1 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT28800 Family [ConnectX-5 Ex]
[root@gputest ~]# ethtool -i eno8303
driver: tg3
version: 4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64
firmware-version: FFV21.81.3 bc 5720-v1.39
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:04:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
[root@gputest ~]# ethtool -i eno8403
driver: tg3
version: 4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64
firmware-version: FFV21.81.3 bc 5720-v1.39
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:04:00.1
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
[root@gputest ~]# ethtool -i eno12399
driver: ice
version: 4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64
firmware-version: 3.00 0x80008943 20.5.13
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:31:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

By checking the domain/bus/function numbers from `lspci` you can compare those with the output of `ethtool` and determine which device names are associated with what model card and from there determine the MAC address.